# How to prevent doctrine:migration:migrate command from rolling back if an older version was specified?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have the following migrations structure within the Doctrine package:

- Version 1
- Version 2
- Version 3 (custom)
- Version 4

Version 3 is not a regular migration because it requires some code calculations and depends on the previous migrations. So it should be executed separately after version 2 and before version 4.

I tried to do the following in my CI/CD script:

```sh
bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate Version2 # prepare
bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate Version3 # run custom migration
bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate # run the rest
```

This works well on the first run. But on the second run, the command `doctrine:migrations:migrate Version2` rolls back everything to the version 2 which is definitely not what I need. What I need is to make commands `doctrine:migrations:migrate Version2` and `doctrine:migrations:migrate Version3` do nothing if newer migrations are already applied. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why not using `bin/console doctrine:migration:execute VersionX` instead?

Comment: Will it execute multiple migrations in case of `doctrine:migration:execute Version2` if ran for the first time?

Comment: Here no. Maybe add a custom condition in Version2/3 to check if you have already execute some SQL queries or something like that?